# Как остановить эту рекурсию после нажатия кнопки, или после определенного количества ее вызова? Python

Tags: python

```
n = int(input("n = ")) # СТЕПЕНЬ
x = int(input("x = ")) # ЧИСЛО  
def rec(n, x):
    if n == 0:
        print(1)
    if n < 0:
        print(1/x**abs(n))
    if n > 0:
        print(x * x**n-1)

    rec(n, x+1)
```

Comment: Задайте какой-то счетчик, который будете передавать в качестве параметра.

Comment: Что считает эта функция?

Comment: Она считает по формуле x в степени n = значение одного операторов if, после этого если 1 из условий if выполняется, то оно считает уже то что в print того оператора if условие которого выполнилось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После нажатия кнопки не выйдет, ведь еще до того, как пользователь успеет ее нажать, выбросится ошибка "maximum recursion depth exceeded"

```
n = int(input("n = ")) # СТЕПЕНЬ
x = int(input("x = ")) # ЧИСЛО
recuresionLevel = 100
def rec(n, x, deph = 0):
    if deph == recuresionLevel:
      return
    if n == 0:
        print(1)
    if n < 0:
        print(1/x**abs(n))
    if n > 0:
        print(x * x**n-1)

    rec(n, x+1, deph + 1)

rec(n, x)
```

Comment: та я уже давно похожий вариант сделал, но забыл что здесь задал вопрос :D

Comment: но ответ засчитаю потому что правильный :)